# Deploy Erlang Application

Tags: sockets, erlang

I would like to run Erlang application on a centOS server for stress testing. I would like to know what I must accomplish to deploy a Erlang application before I send it to the server admin to install and run.

What will I need to tell my admin to properly run an Erlang app on a server? (Basically how can I send him a file and give him an really stupid easy instructions to install it?)

Is their a way to send my app in a executable format that the admin can easily install with? Kinda like PyPy?

How can I perform code swapping? Will the app need to be in it's code state still in order to do this?

I would appreciate any help to make this process easy. Thank you!

*For anyone just passing by: Even though this is my first Erlang app, I highly recommend anyone wanting to build a easy to scale server user Erlang. The benefits are amazing, if you know how to use Erlang properly.*

## Cheers!

Comment: What are you currently using to build your application?

Comment: Right now I'm using Eshell. Surprisingly (unless my Googling is piss poor) their is not many topics or at all from what I seen to deploy Erlang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of deploying an Erlang program (I'm avoiding the word *application* here, as it's somewhat ambiguous in an Erlang context) involves building a [release](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html) (see [this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html) for some background). A release is essentially a packaging of your Erlang code (which often consists of multiple *applications* - hence the ambiguity) and the parts of the runtime system required to run it. The Erlang release system was designed with code upgrades in mind.

If you are using Rebar to build your program, you may find [this article](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades) helpful. In addition to describing how to build a release (the process is a bit tricky) it also explains how you can deploy an upgrade.

A [similar guide](http://ninenines.eu/articles/erlang.mk-and-relx/) is also available for users of erlang.mk. If you're not using one of them already, or a comparable build tool, I strongly encourage you to do so as it makes release handling much less painful.

---

You may also find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796941/how-do-you-compile-an-erlang-program-into-a-standalone-windows-executable) helpful. They list some additional options.